# Oracle ORDS REST - how to return collection query for a handler in PL/SQL mode?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

A query can be returned in a "collection query" mode as a JSON, simply as `SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE`.

In PL/SQL however, this is not possible. How would the equivalent be implemented in this mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to return a `refcursor` from your procedure, as a RESULTSET parameter type.

For example:

```
DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR
        SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY id;
    :result := cur;
END;
```

With your OUT parameter set to bind `result`.

[image]

[Example sample schema, data, and REST Code here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/03/four-options-for-working-with-ords-plsql-refcursors/) - For a longer full example.